# Multiple Domains to vary content on shared host PHP files

Tags: php, dns

I have done some research on this problem without and solution yet.

Setup as follows: Multiple domains say, www.domainA.com and www.domainB.com.
Both domains are mapped a the same hosting folder on a LAMP server. I want the index.php file in that folder to 'know' which domain is accessing the files and vary content from SQL. I.e. load a different client ID specific to that domain.

I've looked into `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` the latter has been clearly stated to be unreliable. I am after a sufficiently robust solution.

`.htaccess` won't do the trick (I wouldn't think?) I was thinking something along the lines of domain DNS IP as a solid source for action. Would greatly appreciate some guidance.

UPDATE: There have been some solutions suggested - I would like to have an SQL table which would contain all expected domains. TABLE clients ('id_client', 'client_name', 'client_url') and query this table returning the 'id_client' to a $variable.

If $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] matches client_url in the database the corresponding id_client is returned. The .htaccess solution - however elegant - would require constant updating of the file. I'd prefer, where possible to keep solutions within the php and database.

What circumstances with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] fail?

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed accomplish this with .htaccess

With modrewrite rewrite domaina.com to index.php?client_id=a

Here's an example of the code, pulled from http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

```
#two domains served from one root..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-one.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/one
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ one/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-two.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^two
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ two/$1 [L]
```

Just modify the regular expressions and routing to suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks Thor!Yes, I hadn't thought that. What I failed to mention however, (sorry) is that they need to be fairly hidden. In your example, if a user was to change index.php?client_id=a to index.php?client_id=b they would be viewing the wrong site. This isn't as robust as I would like. Can you, or anyone else, think of any alternate ways to achieve this?

Comment: @user1108993 @Andrew That's the magic of mod_rewrite!  The rewrites are hidden/internal.  The user sees `domaina.com` but the application sees `?domain=a` or however you choose to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this in your code then the easiest way is to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` which returns the hostname which the user is accessing your site using. For example, if I accessed *http://www.exampleA.com/* then `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` would return `www.exampleA.com`.

Then to do the routing it's a simple case of checking the host against a list of known hostnames and assigning the client_id based on that using a variable.

It may be slightly easier for you to use a framework like [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com) as it has this functionality already built in using [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname) but you should also be able to implement it relatively simply using just standalone PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished in two steps.  First using the aliases in the vhost config for each domain you could point them such that all requests  go to:

*hosting folder*/controller.php/Domain/requested folder/page

A vhosts file to accomplish this for domainA may look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domainA.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/

  Alias /pages /var/www/pages/control.php/DomainA
</VirtualHost>
```

Then control.php would recieve all requests and Apache will sent the variable $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] with everything after control.php. For example if the user goes to www.DomainA.com/folder1/pageC.php then $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would be '/DomainA/folder1/pageC.php'.  Note that it is necessary for the dynamic pages to be separated into there own folder for this solution to work otherwise requests for static content will be directed through control.php causing problems.  This directory structure will can be made invisible to the user if done carefully.

Control.php might then look like this for php pages:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))
{
    $path = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1)); //substr removes leading slash
    $domain = array_shift($path);
    $page = implode('/', $path); //Note: you will want to verify that there is a page name and append 'index.php' if there is not.
}

require_once $page;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ravenex! This is sounding hopeful. An example would be greatly appreciated - I don't quite understand your suggestion so far. Thanks agin.

Comment: I have added some examples.  We use this solution in several Facebook apps we have written to allow users to go to different end points thru a single main control page and also to separate development and production environments.  The only limitation is the segregating of content to avoid images and other content being directed through the controller, but with some clever use of the same principals it to can be avoided.

Comment: This can also be used to create Control-Model-View environments where the user would go to /Control/View and the page first loads the specified control object to process all of the data and then the loads the specified view for that controller.  This allows for convenient separation of code for logic from code for display generation.